# Minecraft sprint and jump problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to sprint (using control key) and I jump and move forward it opens up my keyboard settings which doesn't allow me to play the game properly. I have tried to fix this problem by trying to change the shortcut to go to my keyboard settings or disable it but it won't let me do so. I have also tried to modify my sprint tool (like making it caps lock) which doesn't feel comfortable or work. Has anyone had this problem before? Does anyone know how to fix it? Please let me know what keys you guys use for sprinting or if I can change the setting so that I can sprint and jump at the same time. Thank you.

Comment: Are you *holding* the ctrl key, or just tapping it?

Comment: Are you on windows? Can you post a screenshot of these "keyboard settings" so we can get a better idea of what exactly happens and how to disable it